# How to locate a thread's stack base from a core file?

Tags: linux, debugging, gdb, coredump

I have a core dump that shows a thread dying from a SIGBUS signal while executing `mov %r15d,0xa0(%rsp)`. That seems to tell me that it died because it ran out of thread stack.

But how can I prove it? I cannot seem to find a GDB command to display thread information besides thread backtraces. In this case there is no backtrace. It shows the current function and then 0x0000000000000000. Yet another indication of stack corruption, I think.

I don't have a copy of /proc/[pid]/maps from when the program died. Is there anything in GDB or in the core file I can look at to find the base of each thread stack?

Answer (score 1):

> That seems to tell me that it died because it ran out of thread stack.

Very likely

> But how can I prove it?

```
(gdb) p/x $rsp
$1 = 0x7fffc5791000

(gdb) info target
Symbols from "a.out".
Local core dump file:
    `core', file type elf64-x86-64.
    0x0000000000400000 - 0x0000000000401000 is load1
    ...
    0x00007faaf2240000 - 0x00007faaf2241000 is load14
    0x00007fffc5791000 - 0x00007fffc5f91000 is load15
    0x00007fffc5faf000 - 0x00007fffc5fb0000 is load16
    0xffffffffff600000 - 0xffffffffff600000 is load17
 Local exec file:
  ...
```

Note how `$rsp` is at the (low) end of the `load15` segment, and there is no mapping that "covers" `$rsp-8`

Comment: Sorry for the really late comment. I haven't accepted this because I couldn't make it work for that core file. I tried on an uncrashed program as well, but the load bits don't really match up that well with the threads.